# Portable NPM + NodeJS: standalone JS bundler

Tags: node.js, npm, portability

There are many javascript sandboxes applications (the most popular [runJS](https://runjs.app)), that allows with no root-permissions run node server and a bundler.

Is it possible to make a similar thing?

1. Download Nodejs binaries + NPM
2. Create project using `../../npm init`
3. Then install something `../../npm i whatever`
4. Create a `js` bundle

I tired it in this way, but always was getting errors on the step 3 like

```
npm ERR! enoent spawn sh ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in ...
```

I am using `PATH=$PATH:/path_to_nodejs_binaries_folder`, so it means it should know the exact path to the binary. It does, since it tries to install something, but then fails after

```
npm i esbuild
```

with a log

```
0 verbose cli /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/npm
1 info using npm@9.6.7
2 info using node@v18.17.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 9ms
11 timing config:load:file:/Users/kirill/.npmrc Completed in 2ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 2ms
13 timing config:load:file:/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 19ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 20ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
20 verbose title npm i esbuild
21 verbose argv "i" "esbuild"
22 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 25ms
23 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 4ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 6ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/kirill/.npm/_logs/2023-09-18T18_27_23_128Z-
26 verbose logfile /Users/kirill/.npm/_logs/2023-09-18T18_27_23_128Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 11ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 64ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
33 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
34 silly logfile done cleaning log files
35 timing idealTree:init Completed in 427ms
36 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 2ms
37 silly idealTree buildDeps
38 silly fetch manifest esbuild@^0.19.3
39 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/esbuild 909ms (cache revalidated)
40 silly placeDep ROOT esbuild@0.19.3 OK for: sandbox@1.0.0 want: ^0.19.3
41 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/android-arm@0.19.3
42 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/android-arm64@0.19.3
43 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/android-x64@0.19.3
44 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/darwin-arm64@0.19.3
45 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/darwin-x64@0.19.3
46 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/freebsd-arm64@0.19.3
47 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/freebsd-x64@0.19.3
48 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/linux-arm@0.19.3
49 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/linux-arm64@0.19.3
50 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/linux-ia32@0.19.3
51 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/linux-loong64@0.19.3
52 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/linux-mips64el@0.19.3
53 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/linux-ppc64@0.19.3
54 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/linux-riscv64@0.19.3
55 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/linux-s390x@0.19.3
56 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/linux-x64@0.19.3
57 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/netbsd-x64@0.19.3
58 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/openbsd-x64@0.19.3
59 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/sunos-x64@0.19.3
60 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/win32-arm64@0.19.3
61 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/win32-ia32@0.19.3
62 silly fetch manifest @esbuild/win32-x64@0.19.3
63 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2flinux-ppc64 83ms (cache hit)
64 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2ffreebsd-x64 87ms (cache hit)
65 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2flinux-arm 88ms (cache hit)
66 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2flinux-loong64 87ms (cache hit)
67 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2flinux-s390x 87ms (cache hit)
68 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2fwin32-ia32 86ms (cache hit)
69 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2fwin32-x64 258ms (cache revalidated)
70 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2flinux-x64 282ms (cache revalidated)
71 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2fwin32-arm64 387ms (cache revalidated)
72 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2fnetbsd-x64 468ms (cache revalidated)
73 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2flinux-arm64 479ms (cache revalidated)
74 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2fdarwin-arm64 490ms (cache revalidated)
75 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2flinux-riscv64 507ms (cache revalidated)
76 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2ffreebsd-arm64 542ms (cache revalidated)
77 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2fdarwin-x64 632ms (cache revalidated)
78 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2fopenbsd-x64 1298ms (cache revalidated)
79 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2fandroid-arm64 1423ms (cache revalidated)
80 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2fsunos-x64 1474ms (cache revalidated)
81 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2flinux-mips64el 1565ms (cache revalidated)
82 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2flinux-ia32 2209ms (cache revalidated)
83 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2fandroid-x64 2494ms (cache revalidated)
84 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild%2fandroid-arm 3989ms (cache revalidated)
85 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 4916ms
86 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/android-arm@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
87 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/android-arm64@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
88 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/android-x64@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
89 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/darwin-arm64@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
90 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/darwin-x64@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
91 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/freebsd-arm64@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
92 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/freebsd-x64@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
93 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/linux-arm@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
94 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/linux-arm64@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
95 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/linux-ia32@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
96 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/linux-loong64@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
97 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/linux-mips64el@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
98 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/linux-ppc64@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
99 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/linux-riscv64@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
100 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/linux-s390x@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
101 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/linux-x64@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
102 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/netbsd-x64@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
103 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/openbsd-x64@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
104 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/sunos-x64@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
105 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/win32-arm64@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
106 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/win32-ia32@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
107 silly placeDep ROOT @esbuild/win32-x64@0.19.3 OK for: esbuild@0.19.3 want: 0.19.3
108 timing idealTree:node_modules/esbuild Completed in 39ms
109 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/android-arm Completed in 0ms
110 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/android-arm64 Completed in 0ms
111 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/android-x64 Completed in 0ms
112 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/darwin-arm64 Completed in 0ms
113 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/darwin-x64 Completed in 0ms
114 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/freebsd-arm64 Completed in 0ms
115 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/freebsd-x64 Completed in 0ms
116 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-arm Completed in 0ms
117 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-arm64 Completed in 0ms
118 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-ia32 Completed in 0ms
119 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-loong64 Completed in 0ms
120 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-mips64el Completed in 0ms
121 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-ppc64 Completed in 0ms
122 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-riscv64 Completed in 0ms
123 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-s390x Completed in 0ms
124 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-x64 Completed in 0ms
125 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/netbsd-x64 Completed in 0ms
126 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/openbsd-x64 Completed in 0ms
127 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/sunos-x64 Completed in 0ms
128 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/win32-arm64 Completed in 0ms
129 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/win32-ia32 Completed in 0ms
130 timing idealTree:node_modules/@esbuild/win32-x64 Completed in 0ms
131 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 4957ms
132 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 34ms
133 timing idealTree Completed in 5422ms
134 timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 5423ms
135 timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 4ms
136 silly reify mark retired [
136 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/corepack',
136 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/corepack',
136 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/pnpm',
136 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/pnpx',
136 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/yarn',
136 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/yarnpkg'
136 silly reify ]
137 silly reify mark retired [
137 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/npm',
137 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/npm',
137 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/npx'
137 silly reify ]
138 silly reify moves {
138 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/corepack': '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.corepack-tGiNiAhk',
138 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/corepack': '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/.corepack-JA1KNr1a',
138 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/pnpm': '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/.pnpm-gLXsmPsW',
138 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/pnpx': '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/.pnpx-Rro973H5',
138 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/yarn': '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/.yarn-xaYPSd5p',
138 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/yarnpkg': '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/.yarnpkg-e4rCmu4O',
138 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/npm': '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.npm-yC7sT0sC',
138 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/npm': '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/.npm-Bc4MPcIM',
138 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/npx': '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/.bin/.npx-4mNYq2Fg'
138 silly reify }
139 timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 6ms
140 timing reify:createSparse Completed in 4ms
141 timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
142 silly audit bulk request {
142 silly audit   sandbox: [ '1.0.0' ],
142 silly audit   esbuild: [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/android-arm': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/android-arm64': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/android-x64': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/darwin-arm64': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/darwin-x64': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/freebsd-arm64': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/freebsd-x64': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/linux-arm': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/linux-arm64': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/linux-ia32': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/linux-loong64': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/linux-mips64el': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/linux-ppc64': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/linux-riscv64': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/linux-s390x': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/linux-x64': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/netbsd-x64': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/openbsd-x64': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/sunos-x64': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/win32-arm64': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/win32-ia32': [ '0.19.3' ],
142 silly audit   '@esbuild/win32-x64': [ '0.19.3' ]
142 silly audit }
143 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/win32-x64
144 silly reify mark deleted [
144 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/win32-x64'
144 silly reify ]
145 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/win32-ia32
146 silly reify mark deleted [
146 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/win32-ia32'
146 silly reify ]
147 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/win32-arm64
148 silly reify mark deleted [
148 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/win32-arm64'
148 silly reify ]
149 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/sunos-x64
150 silly reify mark deleted [
150 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/sunos-x64'
150 silly reify ]
151 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/openbsd-x64
152 silly reify mark deleted [
152 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/openbsd-x64'
152 silly reify ]
153 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/netbsd-x64
154 silly reify mark deleted [
154 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/netbsd-x64'
154 silly reify ]
155 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-x64
156 silly reify mark deleted [
156 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-x64'
156 silly reify ]
157 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-s390x
158 silly reify mark deleted [
158 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-s390x'
158 silly reify ]
159 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-riscv64
160 silly reify mark deleted [
160 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-riscv64'
160 silly reify ]
161 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-ppc64
162 silly reify mark deleted [
162 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-ppc64'
162 silly reify ]
163 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-mips64el
164 silly reify mark deleted [
164 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-mips64el'
164 silly reify ]
165 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-loong64
166 silly reify mark deleted [
166 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-loong64'
166 silly reify ]
167 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-ia32
168 silly reify mark deleted [
168 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-ia32'
168 silly reify ]
169 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-arm64
170 silly reify mark deleted [
170 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-arm64'
170 silly reify ]
171 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-arm
172 silly reify mark deleted [
172 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-arm'
172 silly reify ]
173 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/freebsd-x64
174 silly reify mark deleted [
174 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/freebsd-x64'
174 silly reify ]
175 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/freebsd-arm64
176 silly reify mark deleted [
176 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/freebsd-arm64'
176 silly reify ]
177 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/darwin-arm64
178 silly reify mark deleted [
178 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/darwin-arm64'
178 silly reify ]
179 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/android-x64
180 silly reify mark deleted [
180 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/android-x64'
180 silly reify ]
181 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/android-arm64
182 silly reify mark deleted [
182 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/android-arm64'
182 silly reify ]
183 verbose reify failed optional dependency /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/android-arm
184 silly reify mark deleted [
184 silly reify   '/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/@esbuild/android-arm'
184 silly reify ]
185 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/win32-x64 Completed in 13ms
186 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/win32-ia32 Completed in 13ms
187 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/win32-arm64 Completed in 12ms
188 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/sunos-x64 Completed in 12ms
189 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/openbsd-x64 Completed in 12ms
190 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/netbsd-x64 Completed in 13ms
191 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-x64 Completed in 13ms
192 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-s390x Completed in 13ms
193 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-riscv64 Completed in 13ms
194 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-ppc64 Completed in 13ms
195 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-mips64el Completed in 13ms
196 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-loong64 Completed in 13ms
197 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-ia32 Completed in 12ms
198 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-arm64 Completed in 12ms
199 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/linux-arm Completed in 12ms
200 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/freebsd-x64 Completed in 12ms
201 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/freebsd-arm64 Completed in 12ms
202 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/darwin-arm64 Completed in 12ms
203 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/android-x64 Completed in 12ms
204 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/android-arm64 Completed in 12ms
205 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/android-arm Completed in 12ms
206 timing reifyNode:node_modules/esbuild Completed in 97ms
207 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@esbuild/darwin-x64 Completed in 156ms
208 timing reify:unpack Completed in 158ms
209 timing reify:unretire Completed in 0ms
210 timing build:queue Completed in 2ms
211 timing build:link:node_modules/esbuild Completed in 2ms
212 timing build:link Completed in 2ms
213 info run esbuild@0.19.3 postinstall node_modules/esbuild node install.js
214 info run esbuild@0.19.3 postinstall { code: 'ENOENT', signal: undefined }
215 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 7ms
216 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 1ms
217 timing command:i Completed in 5639ms
218 verbose stack Error: spawn sh ENOENT
218 verbose stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
218 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
218 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
219 verbose pkgid esbuild@0.19.3
220 verbose cwd /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script
221 verbose Darwin 21.6.0
222 verbose node v18.17.1
223 verbose npm  v9.6.7
224 error code ENOENT
225 error syscall spawn sh
226 error path /Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/node_modules/esbuild
227 error errno -2
228 error enoent spawn sh ENOENT
229 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
229 error enoent
230 verbose exit -2
231 timing npm Completed in 5995ms
232 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1695061643484
233 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:audit 1695061648932
234 verbose unfinished npm timer auditReport:getReport 1695061648933
235 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1695061649099
236 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1695061649100
237 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1695061649100
238 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall 1695061649104
239 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall:node_modules/esbuild 1695061649104
240 verbose code -2
```

which before line `224` looks absolutely fine.

Here

```
/Volumes/Data/Github/wolfram-js-frontend/Packages/wljs-esm-support/script/
```

is the path to my local `node` folder with js scripts.

Is there any "right" way to do that? Because I have a feeling, that I am digging in a wrong direction. In principle, what I need is

- install any `npm` packages
- bundle them into a single file (using `esbuild`, since it supports stdin/stdout pipes)
- no nodejs installation required
- everything is operated from some other external program, that uses node as a js bundler